# Why does typescript infer a default prop when we dynamically import a javascript file which does not have a default export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, es6-promise, es6-modules

I am dynamically importing a javascript file that exports multiple functions (and does not have a default export)
`const sayHi = import('./sayHi.js')`

I am expecting sayHi's type to be `Promise<{name1: function, name2: function}>`
but it is
`Promise<{default: typeof import('./sayHi.js'), name1: function, name2: function}>`

why does the default prop get added

Here is a codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-dynamic-import-w4nb1?file=/src/index.tsx

why does `__promise__` have a default prop automatically added?
[image]

Comment: @NicholasTower sorry my mistake. I have rectified the link to show the type error now. You can hover over the red squiggly line on line 6

Comment: Can you log the promise result to see how it actually looks at runtime? I guess the "default" prop exists to ensure interoperability when `module.exports` is overwritten, instead of setting properties on it.

Comment: @JonasWilms thank you. I did log it, but there was no default prop. Feel free to see this fork, where i have done it. https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-dynamic-import-forked-oxjqo?file=/src/makeDefaultExport.ts

Comment: how is this a javascript question though

Comment: It might have to do with `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in the tsconfig: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports

Comment: @LindaPaiste thank you. That is a good find. Do you know how i can resolve this? my codebase has import React from 'react',  etc.. in multiple places. And those need allowSyntheticDefaultImports to be true

Comment: Is it actually a problem that you need to fix?  Can you just ignore it?

Comment: @LindaPaiste yes I need to fix it. Right now it is throwing a typescript error and the only way to ignore the error is to use 'any'

Comment: @LindaPaiste Is there a way i can omit the default that is being additionally inferred?

Comment: `makeDefaultExport = <T, K extends keyof T>(promise: Promise<T>, key: K) => {` I'll write an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229305/discussion-between-codeanand-and-linda-paiste).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Synthetic Default Exports

There is an option in your `tsconfig` file called [`allowSyntheticDefaults`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#allowSyntheticDefaultImports) which allows typescript to support Babel's creation of default exports for files which do not have an explicit default.  The default object is a keyed object containing all of the named exports from that file.  If this setting is `true` then all files will have an export called `default` included alongside their named exports.

#### Typing `makeDefaultExport`

Your function `makeDefaultExport` only uses one specific named export from the file, so we can apply stricter typescipt typings to this function and get a more specific return.  Instead of just `keyof T`, we use a second generic `K` for the key.

```
export const makeDefaultExport = <T, K extends keyof T>(
  promise: Promise<T>, key: K
) => {
```

Now this function will return only the type for the specific named export instead of the union of all exports (which was including the default).  The return type is:

```
Promise<{ default: T[K]; }>
```

Edit: I recommend the above approach as it properly handles files where not all named exports have the same type.  In your particular case all of the exports *are* the same type, so we won't get any type widening by returning a union of all export types except the `default`.

```
export const makeDefaultExport = <T>(
  promise: Promise<T>, key: Exclude<keyof T, "default">
) => {
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Linda. Unfortunately this does not work as K could still be default, the type is being infered with default in the union. We need to remove default out. Here is the sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-dynamic-import-forked-pw3lf?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Could you link the babel documentation that explains what babel does (and how to disable it)? It seems that you should use named imports (or a namespace object import) when there is no default export.

Comment: @Bergi if you set `allowSyntheticDefaults: false` in your `tsconfig` then you have to either import named exports or make the "default" yourself like `import * as React from "react"`.  Here are the TS docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports  I'm honestly not sure what controls it on the Babel side of things.  Maybe https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs